# Samsung smart tv : img tag don't display image ,emulator network connection?

Tags: html, samsung-smart-tv

I try to display images that use img tag .
It works when an image is in a folder in my application ,my code is 
 `<img src="images/picture.jpg" >`,
but it displays nothing when my code is `<img src="www.example.com/pic.jpg" >` (I want to display image from website in my app.)
It's about network connection in Emulator?
Sorry for my bad English,

### Thank you.

Edit: this is my screenshots from browser and emulator
http://upic.me/ts/i/ak/browser.jpg , http://upic.me/ts/i/gm/emulator.jpg

Comment: add http:// to the start of www.example.com/pic.jpg.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it doesn't work.

Comment: luke2012 already correctly answered for your question. If it still don't work the problem lays somewhere else. Post here working url to the image you want to use.

Comment: this :`<img alt="alter" src="http://www.flash-slideshow-maker.com/images/help_clip_image020.jpg" >` and I captured screenshot from browser and emulator with Edit message ,Thanks for reply.

Comment: I think it's about Emulator(3.5.2) problem ,Now I change to 2.5.1 version it can display my image,Thank for all comments.

Answer (score 0):

use   full  address (url )of image including http part

like

```
    <img src="http://www.example.com/pic.jpg" >
```

Comment: it works for me always, could you provide some more info and error you getting

Comment: It doesn't have any error but it displays nothing in Emulator.[2012]Samsung TV Emulator(3.5.2) is my Emulator.

Comment: can you try by creating a simple html, try run without Emulator, might be(not sure) Emulator  is creating issue.

Comment: Yes it works when i run with web-browser,but on Emulator it displays nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the full path of the image from the "root" directory, that is

```
<img src="./{your_directory_tree_here}/images/picture.jpg" />
```

The trick here is using "**./**" before your path.